# style tag automatically added to ASP.NET ListBox control

Tags: asp.net, attributes, styles, controls

I have an ASP.NET project with the following line of code:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbxInvoices" runat="server" SelectionMode="multiple" Rows="16"></asp:ListBox>
```

Obviously, I'd like the control to render with 16 rows.  Unfortunately, it refuses to do so...when I check the HTML source for the page, I see the following:

```
<select size="16" name="ctl00$cphMainContent$Wizard1$lbxInvoices" multiple="multiple" id="ctl00_cphMainContent_Wizard1_lbxInvoices" class="DefaultListBox" style="height:100px;width:250px;">
```

Where did the class attribute come from?  And more importantly, where did the style attribute (which is apparently overriding the "size" attribute) come from?  How can I get rid of them?

If I add a `style="height: auto"` attribute to my server side tag, I can get this to work, but that seems weird, and I'd like to just stop it from adding this attribute in the first place.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `<asp:ListBox ID="lbxInvoices" runat="server" SelectionMode="multiple" Rows="16"><asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="One"/></asp:ListBox>` generates this html for me `<select size="16" name="lbxInvoices" multiple="multiple" id="lbxInvoices"><option value="1">One</option></select>`. Could you make sure that your code behind is not adding those extra stuffs?

Comment: It's definitely not the codebehind doing it.  Obviously there's some kind of hidden complexity here.  I can't realistically post the whole front end or back end files (it's quite large and proprietary), but short of it being added dynamically by the back end, I'm just not clear on what it could be.  (Short of ASP.NET deciding to "help" in some strange way.)

Comment: Just create a new Web Form (without master page) inside our web project, and add a dropdownlist to it. Then see what mark up is generated.